Drawing an ellipse with GDI+ while dragging mouse
With a small change, the code under WM_MOUSEMOVE in the link below can draw a 10 pixel thick red ellipse by dragging the mouse. The first Ellipse function erases the previous ellipse.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/using-filled-shapes
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
             if(wParam && MK_LBUTTON) {
                hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
                SetROP2(hdc, R2_NOTXORPEN);

                HGDIOBJ obj_pen = SelectObject(hdc, CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 10, RGB(255,0,0)));

                // If a previous target rectangle exists, erase it by drawing another rectangle on top.
                if(!IsRectEmpty(&rcTarget)) {
                   Ellipse(hdc, rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top, rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom);
                }

                if((pt.x < (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam), LOWORD(lParam), pt.y);
                }
                else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), pt.x, pt.y);
                }
                else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y < (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), pt.y, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam));
                }
                else {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, pt.y, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
                }

                // Draw the new target rectangle.
                Ellipse(hdc, rcTarget.left, rcTarget.top, rcTarget.right, rcTarget.bottom);

                SelectObject(hdc, obj_pen);
                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            }
            return 0;
        }


I want to do the same operation with GDI+. Since I couldn't find the equivalent of the SetROP2 function in GDI+, I have tried the first DrawEllipse function to erase the previous ellipse using background color as pen color. But I couldn't get the result I expected:
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
             if(wParam && MK_LBUTTON) {
                hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

                Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
                graphics.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeHighQuality);

                // If a previous target rectangle exists, erase it by drawing another rectangle on top.
                if(!IsRectEmpty(&rcTarget)) {
                   Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 236, 236, 236), 10); // Background color
                   graphics.DrawEllipse(&pen, (int) rcTarget.left, (int) rcTarget.top,
                                              (int) rcTarget.right-(int)rcTarget.left, (int)rcTarget.bottom-(int)rcTarget.top);
                }

                if((pt.x < (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam), LOWORD(lParam), pt.y);
                }
                else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), pt.x, pt.y);
                }
                else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y < (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), pt.y, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam));
                }
                else {
                   SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, pt.y, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
                }

                // Draw the new target rectangle.
                Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 10); // Pen color
                graphics.DrawEllipse(&pen, (int) rcTarget.left, (int) rcTarget.top,
                                           (int) rcTarget.right-(int)rcTarget.left, (int)rcTarget.bottom-(int)rcTarget.top);

                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            }
            return 0;
        }

The program image is below:

What is the best way to accomplish this operation?
@Jeaninez - MSFT @Simon Mourier
Now the code works fine for drawing a single ellipse or independent ellipses. However, when ellipses are drawn on top of each other, the ellipse area underneath is also erased. How can I solve this problem?
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
{
     if(wParam && MK_LBUTTON) {
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

        Gdiplus::Graphics graphics(hdc);
        graphics.SetSmoothingMode(Gdiplus::SmoothingModeHighQuality);

        // If a previous target rectangle exists, erase it by drawing another rectangle on top.
        if(!IsRectEmpty(&rcTarget)) {
           Gdiplus::Pen pen(Gdiplus::Color(255, 236, 236, 236), 12); // Background color
           graphics.DrawEllipse(&pen, (int) rcTarget.left, (int) rcTarget.top,
                                      (int) rcTarget.right-(int)rcTarget.left, (int)rcTarget.bottom-(int)rcTarget.top);
        }

        if((pt.x < (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
           SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam), LOWORD(lParam), pt.y);
        }
        else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y > (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
           SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), pt.x, pt.y);
        }
        else if ((pt.x > (LONG) LOWORD(lParam)) && (pt.y < (LONG) HIWORD(lParam))) {
           SetRect(&rcTarget, LOWORD(lParam), pt.y, pt.x, HIWORD(lParam));
        }
        else {
           SetRect(&rcTarget, pt.x, pt.y, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        }

        // Draw the new target rectangle.
        Gdiplus::Pen pen2(Gdiplus::Color(255, 255, 0, 0), 10); // Pen color
        graphics.DrawEllipse(&pen2, (int) rcTarget.left, (int) rcTarget.top,
                                   (int) rcTarget.right-(int)rcTarget.left, (int)rcTarget.bottom-(int)rcTarget.top);

        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
    }
    return 0;
}

Program window

The result you get with GDI+ is expected. The problem is when you draw a circle (or even a line) with GDI+, the drawing will be done with anti aliasing. Simplify your code and just draw a red circle and then a grey circle and you'll see that the red circle won't be removed entirely because of antialiasing. You probably need double buffering in order to achieve what you want.

Or remove GDI+ antialiasing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-setsmoothingmode

Dear Simon, removing GDI+ antialiasing actually performs the ellipse erasion. However, I am trying to achieve with antialiasing for the sake quality, if I can.

If you want antialiasing, then there's no other way but remove what has been drawn, including antialised pixels. You could draw a wider (wider by the number of antialises pixels, like ... 5 pixels or so) grey circle for example. Double buffering is more to avoid flickering (which can also be useful)

You are supposed to paint when the OS asks you to.  Something that will be quickly obvious when you minimize and restore the window with your current code, note how the ellipse completely disappears.  Responding to WM_PAINT is additionally useful because you won't have the problem you're asking about.  Call InvalidateRect() to let the OS know that you want to repaint.

I suggest you could try to set the width of the background color pen larger then the width of target color pen (10).
For example:
Set the width to 9:
//Pen pen(Color(255, 236, 236, 236), 10); // Background color
Pen pen(Color(255, 255, 255, 255), 9); // My background color is white


Set the width to 11:
//Pen pen(Color(255, 236, 236, 236), 10); // Background color
Pen pen(Color(255, 255, 255, 255), 11); // My background color is white


